# build a e-commerce scraper which scrapes from all e-commerce websites

Tags: web-scraping

I want to build an e-commerce scraper. first, I search a product on google then crawl through links in the results and scrape few entities like the name of the product , price, seller etc. I didn't find much. I found diffbot but in diffbot not all information is accurate and some information is missing. Can anyone tell me how can it be possible or it is possible or not

Comment: definitely possible. you'll need skills with libcurl, a database, and HTML parsing

Comment: the point is website can be any random website . I want to build a general scraper which extracts data from that website for some website in google result  i will be unaware of dom structure